# Convolution in Matlab hands on

Tags: matlab, math, image-processing, signal-processing, convolution

I got the matrix below:

```
 9 18 27 36 45
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
```

and the kernel:

`-0.5+0.8662i  1  -0.5-0.8662i`

I'm trying to perform the convolution using valid mode:

`ans = conv2(matrix,kernel,'valid');`

The matlab returns:

`0.0000+15.5916i  0.0000+15.5916i  0.0000+15.5916i`

My question is how I can achieve the same results like matlab. I'm trying to do in the matlab in the first point, but the results is different.

```
a =     matrix(1,1) * kernel(1);
a = a + matrix(1,2) * kernel(2);
a = a + matrix(1,3) * kernel(3);
```

`Result: 0-15.5916i`

For some reason the sign of the imaginary is positive using convolution. Why ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe convolution is usually performed by "flipping" the kernel (left-right, up-down) and then sliding it across the matrix to perform a sum of multiplications.

In other words, what matlab is actually computing is:

```
a =     matrix(1,1) * kernel(3);
a = a + matrix(1,2) * kernel(2);
a = a + matrix(1,3) * kernel(1);
```

Answer (score 6):

In the convolution process the kernel is *flipped*. So you have to flip it too in your check; that is, swap `kernel(1)` and `kernel(3)`, as follows:

```
>> a =     matrix(1,1) * kernel(3);
>> a = a + matrix(1,2) * kernel(2);
>> a = a + matrix(1,3) * kernel(1)
a =
  27.0000 +15.5916i
```

This is in accordance with the result of the convolution:

```
>> A = conv2(matrix,kernel,'valid');
>> A(1,1)
ans =
  27.0000 +15.5916i
```

Comment: Like eigenchris said, you have the reason, I forget to flip. Thanks